# Why did the copy operator get called?

Tags: c++, class, oop, virtual

At the last line `myA = foo(myOtherB);`, the function will return type an object of type A, thus; it will be like saying `myA = input, But why is the copy constructor is being?

output:

```
B foo()
 A copy ctor //what calls this?
 A op=
```

For a copy constructor to be called we will have to use the assignment operator during initialization such as: `B newB = myOtherB;`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
 A() { cout << "A ctor" << endl; }
 A(const A& a) { cout << "A copy ctor" << endl; }
 virtual ~A() { cout << "A dtor" << endl; }
 virtual void foo() { cout << "A foo()" << endl; }
 virtual A& operator=(const A& rhs) { cout << "A op=" << endl; }
};

class B : public A {
public:
 B() { cout << "B ctor" << endl; }
 virtual ~B() { cout << "B dtor" << endl; }
 virtual void foo() { cout << "B foo()" << endl; }
 protected:
 A mInstanceOfA; // don't forget about me!
};

A foo(A& input) {
 input.foo();
 return input;
}
int main() {
 B myB;
 B myOtherB;
 A myA;
 myOtherB = myB;
 myA = foo(myOtherB);
}
```

Comment: This code does not compile

Comment: Look at the return type of `foo`.  Notice anything missing?

Comment: `foo()` returns an `A` object *by value*, not *by reference*, so a *copy* of `input` is being returned, and that copy requires the copy constructor to be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> At the last line `myA = foo(myOtherB);`, the function will return type an object of type B

Not true. Your function returns an object of type `A` by value. That means, any value you feed this object to be constructed with will be used to construct a new object of that exact type. So in other words:

```
int foo(float a) {
    return a + 0.5;
}

int u;

u = foo(9.3);

// u has a value of 10
```

Don't expect `u` to hold a value that a int cannot.

Same thing if you use user defined types:

```
A foo(A& input) {
 input.foo();
 return input; // this expression returns a new A
               // using the value of `input`
}

A myA;

myA = foo(myOtherB);

// why would `myA` be anything else than the value of an A?
```

---

So then, what happen here?

> ```
> B foo()
>  A copy ctor //what calls this?
>  A op=
> ```

```
A foo(A& input) {
 input.foo(); // prints B foo, virtual call. a reference to A that
              // points to an object of subclass type B

 return input; // copy `input` into the return value object
}
```

Then, the operator= gets called.

Comment: so return input; is like saying // myA = myOtherB(input); i mean when we return an object, the other object will receive it with the copy constructor right?

Comment: well, `myA` is already constructed, so the `myA` call operator is called with the copy as parameter

Answer (score 0):

See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)

Specifically:

> The copy constructor is called whenever an object is initialized (by direct-initialization or copy-initialization) from another object of the same type (unless overload resolution selects a better match or the call is elided), which includes
>
> - initialization: T a = b; or T a(b);, where b is of type T;
> - function argument passing: f(a);, where a is of type T and f is void f(T t);
> - **function return: return a; inside a function such as T f(), where a is of type T, which has no move constructor.**

Comment: so return input; is like saying // myA = myOtherB(input); or returns to an object will always invoke the copy constructor

Comment: A function returning an object creates a temporary object using the copy constructor. Then the `=` operator assigns the temporary object to yours.

Comment: @cj.vaughter Actually, that's not true, see Guillaume Racicot's answer, especially the last part.  It's the fact that `foo` returns a copy of its input parameter that generates the call to `A`'s copy constructor.  Otherwise, the copy would be [elided](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

Comment: Wow, not sure how I overlooked that, it's literally right there in the quote. Thanks for pointing that out.